# Problem 27e), Chapter 22 in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I am working problem 27e) in chapter 22 of Spivak's Calculus. We are asked to show that if $x_n$ is a sequence of distinct reals and $A$ is a bounded set, then $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n=\limsup A,$$ where $A=\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

$\limsup A$ is the infimum of all **almost upper bounds** of $A$. An almost upper bound $y$ is a number that satisfies $x\geq y$ for finitely many $x\in A$. Moreover, his definition of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$, where $y_n=\mathrm{sup}\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\}$.

The proof proceeds as follows.

> Let $$l=\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n.$$ If $a<l$, then $a<y_n$ for all $n$. Consequently, $a<x_n$ for infinitely many $x_n$, so $a$ is not an almost upper bound for $A$.

Why does $a<x_n$ hold for infinitely many $x_n$? I understand why $a<y_n$ holds for all $n$ (since $y_n$ is a bounded decreasing sequence, $a<l=\mathrm{inf}\{y_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$). Moreover, I do not understand why we require $x_n$ to be distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inequality $a<x_n$ was true only for finitely many $n$'s, then take $N\in\mathbb{N}$ greater than all of those $n$'s. Then $a\geq x_N$, $a\geq x_{N+1}$, and so on. Therefore, $a\ge\sup\{x_N,x_{N+1},\ldots\}=y_N$, which is a contradiction.

And requiring that the $x_n$'s are all distinct is not essential.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. "Not essential", are you saying that $x_n$ being distinct has a purpose after all?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter *at all*.